# How to make text entry into table based on radio button selection in forms in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have created a form with radio buttons in it.

It takes input of the gender of the person and stores it in a table. I want it to store the text "Male" when male is chosen and the text "Female" when female is chosen.

I was unable to do this as when I tried, I was not able to change the value of the option, it takes it as an integer 1,2,3...

In the properties of the button, in the data tab, I have tried changing the option value to "male" and "female" for their respective buttons, but they keep changing back to 1 and 2

I want this to be a text which will go into the database. I have tried doing this, but the data value of the option doesn't seem to change.

Anybody know how to do this??

Regards,
Amir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to unbind your option buttons and create a hidden textbox for gender, then, using the After Update event for the Option Group, update the hidden textbox.

```
Select Case Me.Options
    Case 1
       Me.Gender = "Male"
    Case 2
       Me.Gender = "Female"
    Case Else
       Me.Gender = "N/A"
End Select
```

In the Current event for the form, you can do the reverse:

```
Select Case Me.Gender
    Case "Male"
       Me.Options = 1
    Case "Female"
       Me.Options = 2
    Case Else
       Me.Options = 3
End Select
```

Comment: I did that, but my form shows values of different records and there is a next button to view the values of the next record(in the form). But the problem I am facing by using this is that if I click the radio button as female and click next to view the next records in the form, the radio button shows female for all the records even though it should be male(but the value in the database remains correct)

Comment: I have added a further note.

Comment: Where is the current event? Should I do it in the properties of the options group? Sorry for asking so many questions. I'm new to Access

Comment: ^I got it! It's working fine! Thank you so much for your help! But can you tell me why I had to edit the form's current event for this? I was looking to edit the properties of the option group

Comment: You are translating between numbers and text. Option buttons store numbers, you want to store text.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Do not even try. Use a combo.